# IOS13 Swift Facebook Login

Tags: swift, facebook, ios13

I am using Facebook Swift Package. Completed all configuration, but couldnot find where i should put this code. Because there is no UIViewController anymore

```
// Swift
//
// Add this to the header of your file, e.g. in ViewController.swift 

import FBSDKLoginKit

// Add this to the body
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you see that there are no more `UIViewController`s?

Comment: If you select SWIFT UI LIFE CYCLE while creating a new app, it doesn't create app delegate etc. so There is no file using ViewController as far as I see. I can create a new file and put this ViewController class but then i don't know how to call this functionality from a View.

Comment: You should look at the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)  there is one for interfacing with UIKit